# Prevent hardcoded values in Winform designer file while using User Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to include a calendar like custom user control that picks month and year. In the user control code I am setting two properties, Month and Year to current month and year.

```
public MonthPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_MonthLabels = new Label[]
        {
        lblJanuary,
        lblFebruary,
        lblMarch,
        lblApril,
        lblMay,
        lblJune,
        lblJuly,
        lblAugust,
        lblSeptember,
        lblOctober,
        lblNovember,
        lblDecember
        };

        m_NotSelected = new Font("Sans Serif", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
        m_Selected = new Font("Sans Serif", 8.25F, FontStyle.Bold);
        Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        Year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        lblYear.Text = Year.ToString();
        groupBox2.Visible = false;
        groupBox1.Height = 20;
        CalendarIsDisplayed = false;
        CalendarIsNotChanged = false;
        SetMonthLabelSelected(Month);
    }
```

However, when I include it in my Application form, the designer takes hard coded values for Month and Year. Consequently, when the month changes it still shows me older month.

```
        // tsMonthPicker
        // 
        this.tsMonthPicker.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.tsMonthPicker.CalendarIsDisplayed = false;
        this.tsMonthPicker.CalendarIsNotChanged = false;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 14);
        this.tsMonthPicker.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.tsMonthPicker.Month = 1;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Name = "tsMonthPicker";
        this.tsMonthPicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(215, 20);
        this.tsMonthPicker.TabIndex = 6;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Value = new System.DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.tsMonthPicker.Year = 2017;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Change += new Time_and_Billing_System.MonthPicker.MonthPickerChangeHandler(this.tsMonthPicker_Changed);
        this.tsMonthPicker.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.tsMonthPicker_Load);
```

How do I change my code in user control so that the form designer file automatically takes -

```
this.tsMonthPicker.Month = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
this.tsMonthPicker.Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
```

Comment: Not like that.  Initialize the Value property in the constructor.  And ensure it does not get serialized into InitializeComponent(), give the property the [DesignerSerializationVisibility] attribute so it is Hidden.

Comment: That worked...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put these two lines in the Form_Load method, for the form in which this MonthPicker is embedded.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tsMonthPicker.Month = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
```

In the Object Viewer, while the Form object is chosen, select the Events view (Lightning Bolt), find Load in the list, double-click that space, and this method will appear in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DesignMode` property for this. You don't state if you need a default value of Now each time the app is launched. If that is the case then you don't need the DesignMode.

```
public MonthPicker() 
{
    if (this.DesignMode)
    {
        //These values are only set when the control is created in design mode
        this.tsMonthPicker.Month = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
        this.tsMonthPicker.Year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
}
```